# No se renderiza la data de mi api con React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, api

estoy aprendiendo React haciendo un clon de spotify y por ahora lo que estoy intentando hacer es mostrar secciones de spotify tales como `"las ultimas canciones reproducidas"`, `"top artistas"` y `"top canciones"` mediante un componente llamado Body.js

Yo la data la obtengo desde una libreria de la API oficial de spotify creada por [jmperez](https://github.com/jmperez/spotify-web-api-js) en un useEffect hook en el componente App.js. Una vez que consigo la data de la API, la guardo en un objeto llamado initialState en un archivo llamado `reducer.js`

Este archivo `reducer.js` contiene el estado inicial y la funcion reducer para un custom hook llamado `useDataLayer.js` que basicamente es un useContext hook que pasa como valor un useReducer a todas las ramas de mi programa. De esta forma yo lo que hago es actualizar el initialState desde App.js y accedo a este objeto mediante el `useDataLayer hook` en las distintas ramas de mi programa (entre ellas el componente Body).

El problema que estoy teniendo ahora es que no me esta renderizando las tres secciones yantes mencionadas en spotify, sino que solo me muestra una la cual es la de "top canciones". Lo raro es que por un segundo si renderiza los otros componentes como si en un principio si obtuviera la data y se renderizara pero luego se actualiza y desaparecen. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este problema y me explica porque sucede esto seria genial.

Codigo de App.js

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Player from './components/Player';
import { getTokenFromResponse } from './spotify';
import './styles/App.scss';
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { useDataLayer } from './components/Hooks/useDataLayer';

library.add(fas, fab);


//instancia de la libreria de spotify
const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

function App() {

  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useDataLayer();

  //donde obtengo la data necesaria de la api
  useEffect(() => {
    //funcion para obtener token de acceso
    let accessToken = getTokenFromResponse();
    window.location.hash = '';

    if(accessToken){
      spotify.setAccessToken(accessToken);
      setToken(accessToken);

      //A PARTIR DE AQUI OBTENGO LA DATA QUE NECESITO
      
      // aqui obtengo la data de mi usuario
      spotify.getMe().then((data) =>{
        dispatch({
          type: "GET_USER",
          user: data
        })
      });
      
      spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((data) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_PLAYLISTS",
            playlists: data
        })
      });
      
      spotify.getMyTopTracks({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "GET_TOP_TRACKS",
          top_tracks: data,
        })
      });

      spotify.getMyRecentlyPlayedTracks({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "RECENTLY_PLAYED",
            recently_played: data,
        })
      });

      spotify.getMyTopArtists({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "GET_TOP_ARTISTS",
          top_artists: data,
        })
      });
    }
  }, [token])

  //si token es valido ingresa a Player.js donde dentro se encuentra Body.js y sino vuelve al componente login
  return (
    
      <div className="App">
        {token ? <Player spotify= {spotify} /> : <Login />}
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Codigo Body.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/Body.scss'
import { useDataLayer } from "./Hooks/useDataLayer.js";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

function Body({ spotify }) {

    //obtengo las propiedades de la data necesaria que quiero mostrar en este componente con useDataLayer
    const [{ spotify_recommendations, recently_played,  top_tracks, top_artists }, dispatch] = useDataLayer();
   
    return (
        <div className= "main-body">
            <div className= "body-option">
                <span className= "see-more">Ver Todos</span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'arrow-right']} />
                <div>
                    {
                        //para mostrar la imagen e info del track
                        recently_played?.items.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className= "track" key= {index}>
                                    <img src= {item.track.album.images[1].url} alt= "recently played track"></img>
                                    <div className= "track-data">
                                        <h3>{item.track.name}</h3>
                                        <p>{item.track.artists.map(artist => artist.name).join(", ")}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                        
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className= "body-option">
                <span className= "see-more">Ver Todos</span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'arrow-right']} />
                <div>
                    {
                        //para mostrar la imagen e info del track
                       top_tracks?.items.map((topArtist, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className= "track" key= {index}>
                                    <img src= {topArtist.album.images[1].url} alt= "recently played track"></img>
                                    <div className= "track-data">
                                        <h3>{topArtist.name}</h3>
                                        <p>{topArtist.artists.map(artist => artist.name).join(", ")}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className= "body-option">
                <span className= "see-more">Ver Todos</span>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'arrow-right']} />
                <div>
                    {
                        //para mostrar la imagen e info del artista
                         top_artists?.items.map((topTrack, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className= "track" key= {index}>
                                    <img src= {topTrack.images[1].url} alt= "recently played track"></img>
                                    <div className= "track-data">
                                        <h3>{topTrack.name}</h3>
                                        <p>{topTrack.genres.join(", ")}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            )
                        })   
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Body
```

Codigo de mi custom hook useDataLayer.js

```js
import React, {useContext, createContext, useReducer} from 'react'

let DataContext = createContext();

export function DataLayer({reducer, initialState, children}) {
    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value= {useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export let useDataLayer = () => useContext(DataContext);
```

reducer.js

```js
export const initialState = {
    user: null,
    top_tracks: null,
    top_artists: null,
    top_albums: null,
    playlists: [],
    playlists_tracks: [],
    playing: false,
    spotify_recommendations: null,
    recently_played: null,
    item: null,
}

const reducer = (action, state) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case "GET_PLAYLISTS":
            return {
                ...state,
                playlists: action.playlists,
            };

        case "GET_PLAYLISTS_TRACKS":
            return {
                ...state,
                playlists_tracks: action.playlists_tracks,
            };
        case "GET_USER":
            return{
                ...state,
                user: action.user,
            };
        case "GET_TOP_ARTISTS":
            return{
                 ...state,
                top_artists: action.top_artists,
            };
        case "GET_TOP_ALBUMS":
            return{
                ...state,
                top_albums: action.top_albums,
            };
        case "GET_TOP_TRACKS":
            return{
                ...state,
                top_tracks: action.top_tracks,
            };
        case "GET_RECOMMENDED":
            return{
                ...state,
                spotify_recommendations: action.get_recomended,
            }
        case "RECENTLY_PLAYED":
            return {
                ...state,
                recently_played: action.recently_played,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo y atencion.

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo react también, no me animo a dar una respuesta pero se me hace raro cuando dentro del useEffect de tu función app haces ``if(accessToken) ... setToken(accessToken)`` y finalmente le pasas como segundo parametro del useEfect ``[accessToken]``. Entiendo que ese segundo parámetro le dice al hook que se ejecute cada vez que ``accessToken`` cambie, y el hook está cambiando el token por el simple hecho de no ser null. Eso no sería un loop infinito? o le estoy errando?

Comment: Entiendo que si le pasas un array vacío ``[]`` en lugar de ``[accessToken]``, el hook solo se va a ejecutar cuando se monte el componente. Y creería que es eso lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola agustin, primero que nada gracias por responder y con respecto a tu consulta mira la API de spotify se maneja con un token de acceso, que en mi codigo seria accesToken, que cuando vos accedes a tu cuenta te da este token que la API necesita para saber de que cuenta sacar la data. Entonces yo necesito que tenga en cuenta el useEffect el token porque cuando este cambie, ya que no siempre va a ser el mismo, re renderize todos lo componentes.

Comment: Hola Facu, entonces no te está generando un loop infinito eso? Yo entiendo que 1) Se carga la aplicacion y se ejecuta el useEffect - 2) En la primer linea del useEffect obtenes un accessToken -3) dos lineas despues preguntas "Si existe accesToken" (te da true siempre, pues acaba de obtenerlo, no?) -4) Si el token existe, haces ``spotify.setAccessToken(accessToken); setToken(accessToken);``. PREGUNTA: En este momento, cuando volves a setear el accessToken, no deberia volver a ejecutarse este useEffect? (por el segundo parametro) A partir de ahi, si la respuesta es sí, tenés un loop infinito.

Comment: De todas maneras es la unica observacion que puedo hacer, soy muy novato con esta libreria. Espero que tengas solucion pronto. Saludos.

Comment: Pero osea vos te referis de preguntar si el accessToken existe despues de la linea  `setToken(accessToken); ` ? Voy a intentar aplicar lo que dijiste porque puede ser igual. De todas formas a pesar de ser novatos, dos piensan mejor que uno jajaj. Saludos!

Comment: Jajaja eso si, totalmente. No, lo que sucede es lo siguiente: UseEffect tiene 3 comportamientos (hasta ahora es lo que aprendi) segun lo que le mandas en el segundo parametro. Vos le estas pasando [accessToken]. Podes no pasarle absolutamente nada, un array vacio, o un array como le pasaste vos, con algun elemento. 1) SI NO LE PASO NADA: El hook se va a ejecutar cada vez que detecte CUALQUIER cambio. 2) LE PASO UN ARRAY VACIO: El hook solo se ejecutará una vez, cuando monte el componente y 3)  LE PASO UN ELEMENTO (es tu caso), el hook se va a correr cada vez que el elemento cambie

Comment: Entonces, al ser tu caso el 3, entiendo que el hook se ejecutaría al montarse, y luego cada vez que haces ``setToken(accessToken)`` (ya que el sistema identifica que el state ``token`` acaba de cambiar). Si no fui claro me decis e intento explicarlo de otra manera.

Comment: Al ser un hook que setea un token y hace una llamada a una API, entiendo que solo necesitas que se ejecute una única vez. Por eso mi recomendacion es que pases ``[]`` como segundo parametro, en lugar de ``[accessToken]``

Comment: Hola Agustin, intente hacer lo que me dijiste pero no dio resultado. Yo por lo que entiendo el useEffect se esta ejecutando 5 veces una por cada vez que llamo a la API de spotify, o mejor dicho, hago un cambio en mi pagina. Entonces tengo la teoría de que por cada vez que se ejecuta el useEffect, obtiene los datos de una sección por vez y por ahí no me esta guardando los datos obtenidos las anteriores veces que se ejecuto en el initialState del reducer. Pero la verdad nose como poder solucionarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas cambiar la lógica de tu programa. Al esperar esto:

```
  //A PARTIR DE AQUI OBTENGO LA DATA QUE NECESITO
  
  // aqui obtengo la data de mi usuario
  spotify.getMe().then((data) =>{
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_USER",
      user: data
    })
  });
  
  spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((data) => {
    dispatch({
        type: "GET_PLAYLISTS",
        playlists: data
    })
  });
  
  spotify.getMyTopTracks({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_TOP_TRACKS",
      top_tracks: data,
    })
  });

  spotify.getMyRecentlyPlayedTracks({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
    dispatch({
        type: "RECENTLY_PLAYED",
        recently_played: data,
    })
  });

  spotify.getMyTopArtists({limit: 4}).then((data) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_TOP_ARTISTS",
      top_artists: data,
    })
  });
```

Los datos que esperas llegan en momentos diferentes. Pues son promesas (asincrónicas).

Cuando solo una de las variables haya cambiado en el reducer, el hook:

const [{ spotify_recommendations, recently_played,  top_tracks, top_artists }, dispatch] = useDataLayer();

se pone en efecto. Los otros probablemente tienen definiciones de undefined, y probablemente eso explica porque solamente una variable tiene referente.

En estas circunstancias, en mi reducer yo crearía un sistema de tokens para el conjunto de datos que estoy esperando, y cuando llega el conjunto entero, mando a cambiar la variable de un hook. Cuando tal variable cambia a true o 'listo/ready', la cambio a falso en un useEffect, que por su vez pide el conjunto de datos y hace algo con ellos.

Comment: Osea vos decis de que en mi reducer (que ahora agrego en la pregunta), tenga una propiedad que me diga que cuando consiguio, osea que es true, todos los datos recien ahi los actualice en el initialState y cuando este en el useEffect antes de conseguir los datos lo ponga en false para que los consiga?

Comment: Sí, (1) en el reducer, necesitar gestionar, digamos, la llegada de las 4 variables/propiedades. (2) cuando hayan llegado las 4 (puedes usar un array que deba llegar a la suma de 4, digamos), cambias el valor de la variable que monitorea el hook de tu script a true, y (3) construyes tu component/ui..

Comment: +1 @JoeCollentine muy buena respuesta y bien explicada